# Installing IIS on XP via command line

Tags: iis, command-line, windows-xp

i have this command for Windows 7:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication
```

But the dism command dont work for XP.
I searched the internet and found

```
sysocmgr
```

Is it like the command dism?

Does anyone have a command for XP like the dism command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see also [Creating an Answer File (IIS 6.0)](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/efefcb53-b86e-4cac-9b4b-fcf5f1145aa9.mspx?mfr=true);

Create a file called `IIS_Unattended.txt` and specify the components you need, for example:

```
[Components]
iis_www = ON
iis_common = ON
iis_inetmer = ON
aspnet = ON
complusnetwork = ON
```

execute the following command to start the installation:

```
Sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:IIS_Unattended.txt
```